# Makefile To Compile Multiple Files

Tags: c, makefile, linker

I am trying to compile my TCP client server program through Make but I can not get everything linked together.

My current files I am using:

```
 client.c
 connectioninfo.c
 connectioninfo.h
 server.c
 splinter.c
 splinter.h
```

All `.c` files use the two `.h` files in their code.

Here is what my makefile looks like:

```
 splinter : server.o client.o splint.o connectioninfo.o
 server.o: server.c splinter.h connectioninfo.h
      gcc -o server server.c
 client.o: client.c splinter.h connectioninfo.h
      gcc -o client client.c
 splint.o: splinter.c splinter.h connectioninfo.h
      gcc -o splint splinter.c
 connectioninfo.o: connectioninfo.c splinter.h connectioninfo.h
      gcc -o connectioninfo connectioninfo.c
```

I get the errors :

```
  gcc -o server server.c
  /tmp/ccAu7sDE.o: In function `main':
  server.c:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `alloc_serverinfo'
  server.c:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to `getconnectioninfo'
  server.c:(.text+0xcd): undefined reference to `port'
  server.c:(.text+0xdc): undefined reference to `host'
  server.c:(.text+0xe7): undefined reference to `s_bind'
  server.c:(.text+0x1a5): undefined reference to `s_accept'
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  Makefile:4: recipe for target 'server.o' failed
  make: *** [server.o] Error 1
```

Any idea on how i can get everything to compile? Thanks

Comment: you have to link them

Answer (score 2):

You are currently calling `gcc` to build applications, not object files, for each source file. Please use the option `-c` and give the appropriate file name for the output, for example

```
gcc -c -o server.o server.c
```

Now change the rule for the application so that it is linked:

```
splinter : server.o client.o splint.o connectioninfo.o
    gcc -o splinter server.o client.o splint.o connectioninfo.o
```

To debug your `Makefile` and see what commands will be generated without executing them you can use

```
make -n
```

You can call commands explicitly like i.e. `gcc -c -o server.o server.c` in your shell to check each step.

Oh, and you can name the object file `splinter.o` which is compiled from the source file `splinter.c`. There will be no problem with the resulting executable `splinter`.

Now you could also simplify your `Makefile` to use automatic variables; please see the [documentation for make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

All put together, you could use:

```
splinter : server.o client.o splinter.o connectioninfo.o
    gcc -o $@ $^

server.o: server.c splinter.h connectioninfo.h

client.o: client.c splinter.h connectioninfo.h

splinter.o: splinter.c splinter.h connectioninfo.h

connectioninfo.o: connectioninfo.c splinter.h connectioninfo.h

%.o: %.c
    gcc -o $@ $<
```

Answer (score 0):

For compiling multiple files you will need to do it in two steps:

1. Compile each source file into an object file (note the use of `-c` to compile only) as the busybee suggested:

```
    somefile1.o : somefile1.c
        gcc -c somefile1.c -o somefile1.o

    somefile2.o : somefile2.c
        gcc -c somefile2.c -o somefile2.o
```

2. Link your object files - create `myapp` executable

```
    myapp : somefile1.o somefile2.o
        gcc somefile1.o somefile2.o -o myapp
```